# AppEngine model structure for user/follower relations

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a users who have "followers". I need to be able to navigate up and down the tree of users/followers. I'm eventually going hit [AppEngine's 1mb limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/#Python_Quotas_and_limits) on entity entries if I use [ancestor relations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Ancestor_paths) if a user has many followers.

What's the best way to structure this data on AppEngine?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ancestor relations for a simple reason that your use case allows circular references (I follow you, you follow me).

The solution depends on your expected usage patterns. You can choose between two options:

(A) In each suer entity store a list of IDs of other users that this user is following.

(B) Create a separate entity that has two properties: "User" and"Follower". Every entity will represent a single "connection" between users.

While the first option seems simpler, you may run into [exploding indexes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes#Python_Index_limits) problem. Besides, it may turn out to be a more expensive solution as each change in user relationships will require an overwrite of a user entity with updates to all of its other indexes. The second solution does not have these drawbacks, but may require a little extra code.

Comment: Hey, I don't actually have circular references. Maybe my original description should have mentioned my structure is more like an invite tree. So a single person at the top. I need to be able to navigate up and down that tree, and the top person could in theory have hundreds of thousands of child, and child of child etc relations.

Comment: How do you prevent circular references if this is a deep tree? In either case, you will not be able to update your data at all if you try to use ancestor relations with such a huge number of entities in a single entity group.

Comment: It's an invitation tree. You can't invite someone who has already been invited. At the top level I will need to get a list of users that "user 1" has invited, and then from that list I will need to get the users that they invited, and so on. So if "user 1" invited 2 people, and those two people invited 2 more people, I would need to be able to retrieve all 8 people who have joined, effectively because of user 1.